# Error while using Boost with Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, boost

I am using Boost with Visual Studio 2008 and I have put the path to boost directory in configuration for the project in C++/General/"Additional Include Directories" and in Linker/General/"Additional Library Directories". (as it says here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#build-from-the-visual-studio-ide)

When I build my program, I get an error:

fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/python.hpp': No such file or directory

I have checked if the file exists, and it is on the path.

I would be grateful if anyone can solve this problem.

The boost include path is `C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_36_0\boost`.

Linker path is `C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_36_0\lib`.

The file `python.hpp` exists on the include path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where is the file located, and which include path did you specify? (And how is the file `#include`'d)

There's a mismatch between some of these But it's impossible to say what's wrong when you haven't shown what you actually did.

**Edit**:

Given the paths you mentioned in comments, the problem is that they don't add up.
If the include path is `C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_36_0\boost`, and you then try to include 'boost/python.hpp", the compiler searches for this file in the include path, which means it looks for `C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_36_0\boost\boost\python.hpp`, which doesn't exist.

The include path should be set to `C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_36_0` instead.

Comment: While I'm sure it's just a configuration problem, fla wrote that he already did that.

Comment: true. I just skimmed the question, only noticed that he'd added the linker path. Anyway, changed my answer :p

Answer (score 2):

How do you include it? You should write something like this:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
```

Note that `Additional Include Directories` settings are differs in `Release` and `Debug` configurations. You should make them the same.

If boost placed to `C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_36_0\` you should set path to `C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_36_0\` without `boost` in the end.

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

The boost include path is 
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_36_0\boost

and linker path is
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_36_0\lib

the file python.hpp exists on the include path

Comment: You should set include path to `C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_36_0\` without boost in the end.

Comment: C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_36_0\boost should be
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_36_0\